# How to use multiple line charts in one page

Tags: javascript

I have a line chart where the values are from DB, and it plots well.

Here's the code
**Chart #1 :**

```
<?php
    $dataPoints = array( 
        array("y" => $todayv1, "label" => $todayh1),
        array("y" => $todayv2, "label" => $todayh2),
        array("y" => $todayv3, "label" => $todayh3),
        array("y" => $todayv4, "label" => $todayh4),
        array("y" => $todayv5, "label" => $todayh5)
    );
    $dataPoints2 = array(
       array("y" => $yv1, "label" => $yh1),
       array("y" => $yv2, "label" => $yh2),
       array("y" => $yv3, "label" => $yh3),
       array("y" => $yv4, "label" => $yh4),
       array("y" => $yv5, "label" => $yh5)
   );
?>   

<script>
     window.onload = function () {

     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         title: {
              text: ""
                },
         axisY: {
              title: ""
                },
         data: [{
              type: "line",
              name: "Today",
              showInLegend: true,
              visible: true,
              dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
              },
              {
              type: "line",
              lineDashType: "dash",  
              name: "Yesterday",
              showInLegend: true,
              visible: true,
              dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
             }]
           });
             chart.render();
       }
</script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

And I tried to replicate the same graph with same values in the same page.

> But the first graph is not being plotted when I add the code for
>   second graph.  I even changed the variable names in JS to prevent over
>   writing values, yet the same.  Only one graph is being plotted in one
>   page.

Here's the code for second graph
**Chart #2 :**

```
<?php
    $dataPointsy = array( 
       array("y" => $todayv1, "label" => $todayh1),
       array("y" => $todayv2, "label" => $todayh2),
       array("y" => $todayv3, "label" => $todayh3),
       array("y" => $todayv4, "label" => $todayh4),
       array("y" => $todayv5, "label" => $todayh5)
    );
    $dataPointsy2 = array(
       array("y" => $yv1, "label" => $yh1),
       array("y" => $yv2, "label" => $yh2),
       array("y" => $yv3, "label" => $yh3),
       array("y" => $yv4, "label" => $yh4),
       array("y" => $yv5, "label" => $yh5)
    );
?>   

<script>
     window.onload = function () {

     var charty = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainery", {
         title: {
             text: ""
                },
         axisY: {
             title: ""
                },
         data: [{
             type: "line",
             name: "Today",
             showInLegend: true,
             visible: true,
             dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointsy, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
           },
           {
           type: "line",
           lineDashType: "dash",  
           name: "Yesterday",
           showInLegend: true,
           visible: true,
           dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointsy2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
         }]
       });
       charty.render();
    }
</script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainery" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Is the second graph on the same page? Is it possible that you use canvasjs.min.js twice?

Comment: @AlekseyDubinskiy yes, the second graph is on the same page and add the script canvasjs.min.js twice on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `canvasjs` js file multiple time on same page. You can include it once and use it like:

```js
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{ text: "Live Data" },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints : [
          { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
          { label: "orange", y: 15  },
          { label: "banana", y: 25  },
          { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
          { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
      ]
    }]
});
var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainery",{
    title :{ text: "Live Data" },
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints : [
          { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
          { label: "orange", y: 15  },
          { label: "banana", y: 25  },
          { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
          { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
      ]
    }]
});
 
chart1.render();
chart2.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="chartContainery" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

---

Or, if you want to display the charts side-by-side you can also do it like:

```js
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{ text: "Live Data" },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints : [
          { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
          { label: "orange", y: 15  },
          { label: "banana", y: 25  },
          { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
          { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
      ]
    }]
});
var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainery",{
    title :{ text: "Live Data" },
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints : [
          { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
          { label: "orange", y: 15  },
          { label: "banana", y: 25  },
          { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
          { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
      ]
    }]
});
 
chart1.render();
chart2.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 45%; height: 370px; display: inline-block"></div>
<div id="chartContainery" style="width: 45%; height: 370px; display: inline-block"></div>
```

---

So, update your code like:

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="chartContainery" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>
   // All the chart related js code here
</script>
```

**For more info:**

- [Render Multiple Charts in a Page](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/render-multiple-charts-in-a-page/)

Comment: If i' m to take out the `window.onload = function () {` the chart wouldn't load at all. how did it worked for you. And i tried your snippet as it is, yet i still see nothing.

Comment: This because you have your js code first then your HTML.. try to put all chartContainer and chartContainery div HTML first, then put the `<script>` with all your js code. The snippet here does that for us internally.